# Email Interactive Form on Landing Page Rendering Badly

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, form, interactive-email

Having an issue using an interactive email form on a cloudpage landing page. The form looks great in content builder, once it is saved in cloud pages and published it looks terrible. The drop down menus are suddenly squished and tiny, when opening the form via the link it looks very bad from a UX perspective.

Has anyone had this issue and if so how do I adjust how the form is rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was previously fixed by using a different layout, used the radial to do a custom setup that was just not appropriate and led to the crazy rendering. If you are having the same issue try a different setup for the email form (review, feedback, etc)